# Comparing version numbers with decimal points

Tags: android, kotlin

I have to check that current app version is greater or lesser than the available new version?

Actually, I am getting **newVersion as 0.0.2** and oldVersion as 5

To check I am doing as below :

`btnInitiateUpdate.isEnabled = it.data.result.versionNumber.toDouble() > (prefManager.getCurrentFirmwareVersionFromBMS().toString()?.toDouble`())!!

but this gives me :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1890)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
```

To resolved this I have tried it as below :

```
val vCurrent = it.data.result.versionNumber.split("\\.".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
    val vNew = prefManager.getCurrentFirmwareVersionFromBMS().toString().split("\\.".toRegex()).toTypedArray()

    for (pos in vCurrent.indices) {
        // compare v1[pos] with v2[pos] as necessary
        if (vCurrent[pos].toInt() > vNew[pos].toInt()) {
            btnInitiateUpdate.isEnabled = false
        } else if (vCurrent[pos].toInt() < vNew[pos].toInt()) {
            btnInitiateUpdate.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

But in this case it gives me

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

How can I compare the multi point values like 5 with 0.0.2 or 0.1.0 with 0.1.2 or something else accurately ?

Thanks.

Comment: This approach couldn't work even if there were only one decimal place. For example, as a floating point number 1.2 is bigger than 1.10, but as a version number, 1.10 is bigger than 1.2. If you know for sure there are only integers separated by decimals, you could use `split()` to split it by decimal points and then compare the component integers. But if the version might have symbols like `-` and suffixes like `a` and `b`, it will be much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Semantic versioning in general can quite tricky. For example `2.3.10.RELEASE` < `2.4.5` (a Spring example). There are some libraries out there that can do this for you. Example: https://github.com/skuzzle/semantic-version

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function to get a weighted integer value of a version in x.x.x format.
It will weigh every value of the version to the power of 10, for example, 1.2.3 will return 123.
Of course, if you need more digits you can increase the multiplier base:

Using a base of 100 you will get 10203 if you need to compare the version with greater than 10 values (eg. 1.10.11).

```
fun getVersionValue(version: String): Int {
    var result = 0
    val versionSplit = version.split("\\.".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()

    var i = 0
    for (index in versionSplit.size - 1 downTo -1 + 1) {
        val exponent = (i + i).toDouble()
        val multiplier = if (i > 0) 10.0.pow(exponent).toInt() else 1
        val versionValue = try { versionSplit[index].toInt() * multiplier } catch(e: NumberFormatException) { 0 }

        result += versionValue
        i++
    }

    return result
}
```

Then compare your versions with

```
val oldVersion = getVersionValue("0.0.2")
val newVersion = getVersionValue("0.0.3")

if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
    // Need some updates...
}
```